# Full example of CRUD operation for 3 level nested subgrid

Tags: php, jqgrid, jqgrid-php, subgrid

I want to implement a jQgrid of 3 level nested subgrid, I am able to create the 3 level nested subgrid, however, the CRUD operation seems to be at flaw.

Kindly help me if anyone has Full example of CRUD operation for 3 level nested subgrid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm able to sort things out using this as reference.
http://www.trirand.net/d...tion/php/_2v90kvcfq.htm

Hope it helps anyone out there.

Comment: [http://www.trirand.net/d...tion/php/_2v90kvcfq.htm](http://www.trirand.net/d...tion/php/_2v90kvcfq.htm) makes 404.